# Custom view directories for Play Framework 2.x not working

Tags: view, playframework, directory, customization, playframework-2.2

I'm new to using Play Framework (2.2.x) and I am having a tough time figuring out how to render views **not located** in the `\app\views` directory.

My project is organized such that each section (directory) of the app has it's own views, controllers, services, repositories... etc. It's a structure I'd like to keep. It looks something like this:

```
\app\Game\Views
\app\Game\Controllers
\app\Game\Services
\app\Game\Repositories

\app\Players\Views
\app\Players\Controllers

\app\Common\Views
\app\Common\Repositories
... etc
```

Views, as you can see from above, are in sub-directories in each app section. View locations vary from one sub-directory deep to many more. It looks something like this:

```
\app\Game\Views
\app\Game\Views\sports.scala.html
\app\Game\Views\dates.scala.html
\app\Game\Views\invites.scala.html

\app\Common\Views\Layouts
\app\Common\Views\Layouts\default.scala.html
\app\Common\Views\Partials
\app\Common\Views\Partials\Headers\default.scala.html
\app\Common\Views\Partials\Headers\onboarding.scala.html
... etc
```

If I follow the default 'Play' way of rendering a view located in `\app\views` everything works fine:

```
views.html.index.render()
```

I'm having a tough time adapting the default 'Play' way to recognize views located outside of the `\app\views` directory. I'm sure there's some sort of configuration or way of identifying those views, but I just can't see it in the documentation.

How do I render a view **not located** in the `\app\views` directory?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't have to do much, but just address it correctly.

Assume you have your view in `app\common\views\index.scala.html`, then in your controller you have to refer to it `common.views.html.index`. Note the extra `common`.

You can check the actual packages of the classes generated from the templates by looking into `target/scala-2.10/src_managed/main/<your-prefixes>/views/html/`

Comment: Thank you @lpiepiora! That worked perfectly. Thank you for also mentioning the _target_ views path.

Comment: In later versions of play you can find the generated templates in target/scala-2.10/twirl/...