# Play Framework custom views directory

Tags: scala, playframework-2.4, play-templates

I found an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23724633/custom-view-directories-for-play-framework-2-x-not-working) to my question, however implementing it still causes errors. The only difference being the version of the Play framework

So, I've created a custom directory within app as follows:

```
app
  └ custom
         └ controllers
         └ models
         └ views
```

When trying to access views from within a controller with this code:

```
Ok(custom.views.html.index())
```

I get a compile error as follows:

```
object custom is not a member of package views
```

The answers also suggests to interrogate the corresponding `target/...` directory which, upon inspection, does has the class in the correct structure: `custom.views.html.list`

Any suggestions?

If I've omitted any necessary information, please let me know and I'll update my question as soon as I can

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

If you check the [Twirl project](https://github.com/playframework/twirl) (Play's templating engine) on Github, you'll find the answer:

> To configure the source directories where template files will be found, use the sourceDirectories in compileTemplates key. For example, to have template sources alongside Scala or Java source files:

```
sourceDirectories in (Compile, TwirlKeys.compileTemplates) := (unmanagedSourceDirectories in Compile).value
```